# Flexbox styles not working in React Styled Component

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styled-components

I've been struggling with the styling of my React app using StyledComponents, however I've succesfully re-created & fixed the issue in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/simoncunningham/pen/mdwMgyL

(Basically using `flex: 1`) to ensure the checkbox expands to the full width of parent) however I cannot reflect this change with my StyledComponents, can anyone see where I might be missing something?

```css
const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem
  width: 200px;
`;

const StyledHiddenInput = styled.input`
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;

  &[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label::after {
    background-image: url("${checkboxImage}");
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
`;

const StyledLabel = styled.label`
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 24px;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;

  &::before {
    display: block;
    top: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 4px;
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 80%;
  }
`;

const StyledLabelWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 0;
`;
```

```js
<StyledWrapper>
   <StyledHiddenInput />
   <StyledLabel>
      <StyledLabelWrapper>{label}</StyledLabelWrapper>
   </StyledLabel>
</StyledWrapper>
```

Screenshot of output from Codepen (working as expected with checkbox displaying as far right as possible)::

[image]

Screenshot of output from Styled Component:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by updating the `width` on StyledWrapper like so:

```
const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem
  width: 100%;
`;
```

which allowed the content to grow to the full width of its container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the last 2 properties added):

```css
.label::before {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: please consider adding lang-CSS for correct syntax.